# Rabbitmq : manually created user is not working

Tags: grails, rabbitmq

I just start using **Rabbitmq** and I'm trying to use this with grails. I set up rabbitmq successfully in grails. While creating connection when i use username = "guest" and password = "guest" it works fine, but when i try to use manually created user it throws me some error which is as below :

```
    Error initializing the application: null
    java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:376)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:83)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:595)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:637)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionContextImpl.start(ConnectionContextImpl.groovy:101)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.start(ConnectionManagerImpl.groovy:191)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$_start_closure4.doCall(ConnectionManagerImpl.groovy:176)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.start(ConnectionManagerImpl.groovy:174)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContextImpl.startConnections(RabbitContextImpl.groovy:193)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContextImpl.start(RabbitContextImpl.groovy:78)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContextProxy.start(RabbitContextProxy.groovy:188)
    at RabbitmqNativeGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(RabbitmqNativeGrailsPlugin.groovy:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:348)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:221)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534)
    ... 1 more
```

I provided all permission to that user and added administrator as a tag. Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to create the user from a different machine?  The credentials "guest:guest" will only work if you're connection is being made on the host machine itself (by default, this can be changed but isn't recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i was facing the same issue you just check or follow the steps first:-

1)Create a user with command 
`sudo rabbitmqctl add_user username password`

2)Now set tag for your username as admin
`sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags username administrator`

3)Now create a new virtualHost by
`sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost test`

4)After that give the full permission 
`sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p test username ".*" ".*" ".*"`

5)Now finally in your config file define

> connection host: "Ip for your server", username: "admin", password: "password" , virtualHost: "test"

Now run your code again it will sucessfully run.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks Praveen its working fine. You really saved my life :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you manually need to create a virtual host first and then try and add your created user with that.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the replying, but i created virtual host and it doesn't seems to be working.